# Width and Height In react-native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

please explain by what principle view sizes with element style are formed. I learned FlexBox however it breaks all my understanding.

code

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.element}>
          <View style={styles.element1}></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  element: {
    // width: '100%',
    // height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    // top: '5%',
  },
  element1: {
    width: '50%',
    height: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

Comment: Why not use `display: flex;` on your container? React is just a means of serving up content. CSS is still CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex: 1` instead of 
`width: '100%', height: '100%',`.

The `Flex: 1` means the component (In case, the view) have a priority value of `1`, wich means, if there'snt another component **on the same view** with `flex: 1`, the component will take the entire screen.
If, there's **two components with** `flex: 1`, each one will take 50% of the entire screen.

Here's the documentation: [React native flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)